# Why are my indent settings ignored in an XmlWriter in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a Powershell script which formats an XML document. I would like the indentation to be tabbed, so I'm using an XmlWriter and passing it what I deem to be the appropriate settings.

However, the result is indented with spaces instead:

Actual result:
[image: The actual result, with spaces]

Desired result:
[image: The desired result, with tabs]

My function is as follows:

```
function Format-XML ($xml) 
{ 
    $stringbuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
    $settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
    $settings.Indent = $true
    $settings.IndentChars = "`t`t"

    $xmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create($stringbuilder, $settings)
    $xml.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter) 
    $xmlWriter.Close()

    return [xml]$stringbuilder.ToString()
}
```

If I set $settings.IndentChars to `` x`t`t `` I can see it taking effect - each line is prefixed with x followed by a pair of tabs, as expected.

*Why are my IndentChars being ignored when I specify only a pair of tabs?*

Comment: How are you testing your output?  If you change your return method to use `$stringbuilder.ToString()` (i.e. no explicit cast to xml) you'll see the response you expect displayed on screen (i.e. with both tabs), so my guess is the bug's in other code where you're outputting the content.

Comment: Thanks @JohnLBevan - I am passing the contents of an existing XML file to the method, and calling:
    $xmlDocument = Format-XML($xmlDocument)
$xmlDocument.Save($filePath)
Any thoughts on why this would result in the tabs being replaced with spaces, please? Am I missing a trick in the .Save method?

Comment: A quick test verified that you're spot-on, @JohnLBevan - thanks! Will post the solution imminently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Format-XML ([xml]$xml) 
{ 
    $stringbuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
    $settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
    $settings.Indent = $true
    $settings.IndentChars = "`t`t"

    $xmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create($stringbuilder, $settings)
    $xml.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter) 
    $xmlWriter.Close()

    $xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
    $xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
    $xmlDoc.LoadXml($stringbuilder.ToString())
    return $xmlDoc
}
```

i.e. the issue's caused by the explicit cast to XML, since there's nothing in the original code telling it to preserve white-space.

The change above creates a new XMLDocument, sets the preserve white-space option to true, then parses your string and returns the resulting XML.

There may be a better way to do this via options on the XmlWriter (I'd be surprised if there weren't), but I'm not familiar enough to know what's needed...

Answer (score 1):

One solution - there was nothing wrong with the method above, but seemingly with how I was saving the resultant XML.

Rather than casting the return value of the Format-Xml method as XML, I'm now returning a string:

```
#return [xml]$stringbuilder.ToString()
return $stringbuilder.ToString()
```

The code that resulted in spaces rather than tabs:

```
$xmlDocument = Format-XML($xmlDocument)
$xmlDocument.Save($filePath)
```

The new code, that takes the result of Format-Xml as a string, and results in the desired (tabbed) output, is this:

```
$formattedXmlString = Format-XML($xmlDocument)
$formattedXmlString | out-file $filePath
```

Thanks to @JohnLBevan for putting me on the right track.